# Angular 4 pipe just for test

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I created pipe like below:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'hasString' })
export class HasString implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any): any {
  let test = value + "1234";
  return test;
  }
}
```

I put it on some string but it doesn't work. :(

Comment: how you have used it in the component?

Comment: <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.messageText | hasString}}</mat-cell>

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What error message do you get? Does it display nothing? Also what are you putting inside transform? I would not suggest to use any ever.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine here,

```
export class HasString implements PipeTransform {

   transform(value: any): any {
  let test = value + "1234";
  return test;
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ App,HasString ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
```

**[`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/a2Nm9fcEGKhYuxuUxCRx?p=preview)**